# Quick Search? (custom configuration)

Tags: search

Is there a way to modify the keys to access quick search?

I wanted to use ATL+SPACE or the COMMAND key.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way!!!  AWESOME!  Modify the Keyboard in Linux!

[image: Quick Search]